# Replicate scrapy shell abilities in PyCharm python console

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

How can I run the `scrapy shell` emulation inside PyCharm IPython console? I want to keep the ability to run snippets of code from editor by Alt+Shift+E

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working by running the following python snippet:

```
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import sys
sys.argv = ['scrapy', 'shell', 'http://scrapy.org']
execute()
```

If you get the following error:

```
MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of InteractiveShellEmbed are being created.
```

then you have to add to the scrapy.cfg the following line:

```
shell=python
```

Comment: When I try this method I got `MultipleInstanceError` with `ipython` (my preferred shell) even with `shell=ipython` as written in [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#configuring-the-shell) but with ordinary shell it's working.

Comment: One more limitation - not working in remote interpreter